OpenLayers update point position in database via Node.js Express
I use a function to give the user the possibility to drag a point (after 'rightclick') in OpenLayers to a new position. The new position is then updated automatically in a database.
My code works, but new to Node.js and Express I wonder if this is the best way to implement this functionality. I would like to have a response if the update had been successful.
Here is my code so far:
in OpenLayers frontend
// make feature (tree) draggable and save new position to database
map.getViewport().addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(map.getEventPixel(e),
        function (feature) {
                return feature;
        });

    if (feature) {
        var dragInteraction = new Translate({  
            features: new Collection([feature]),
            style: null
        });
        map.addInteraction(dragInteraction);
        
        dragInteraction.on('translateend',function(){    
            var new_coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();

            fetch(expressBaseUrl + 'baeume/update?gid='+ feature.get('id') + '&lng=' + new_coord[0] + '&lat=' + new_coord[1], {
                method: 'PUT',
                mode: 'cors',
                body: JSON.stringify(), 
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
              })
              .then(() => {
                console.log('updated');
             }).catch(err => {
               console.error(err)
             });

            map.removeInteraction(dragInteraction);
        });
    } else {
        ; // do nothing
    }
});

in Express backend
import express from 'express';
import pg from 'pg';
import cors from 'cors';
import dbConfig from './dbConfig.cjs';
import fs from 'fs';
import https from 'https';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Middleware for CORS
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Configuration of the database connection
const { Pool } = pg;
const pool = new Pool(dbConfig);


// route to update position of tree in database
app.put('/data/baeume/update', (req, res) => {
  const sql = "UPDATE trees SET the_geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(" + req.query.lng + "," + req.query.lat + "),4326) WHERE gid ="+ req.query.gid+";";
  pool.query(sql, (err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res); // if (err) ...
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Express-Server is listening on port ${port}`);
  });


This is not a GIS question. It is a plain nodejs/express question. But your put route should call some function on the res object that returns a response. In the simplest form call res.status(200).end() for success and res.status(500).end() (or some other applicable HTTP status code) on error. If you want to provide some sort of response describing the result use .send() or json() instead of end() and provide a response body,
